# Prediction map using spatial raster datase

Tags: spatial, raster, prediction

Actually, I am a new user in R environment. and i faced few dilemmas, if you could help me with some tips regarding:
My data represent landslides locations and conditioning factors contain the following:
I have spatial data for landslide assessment in .tiff format.
1)Dependent: Training and testing (1=landslide, 0= no landslide, -9999 value refer to nodata)
2)Independent variables, slope, elevation..etc.

My question: should i keep using raster format and search for suitable analysis methods like regressions . OR, i need to convert them to ascii, and use the huge amount of tools available. 
Note: if i convert my data into ascii, it would develop uncertainty, moreover, ascii file size will be huge (60 MB).

Worth to mention that my training data represents polygon converted to raster.
I am totally overwhelmed. kindly any suggestions.

Omar

Answer (score 1):

You give very little information. For example you are not saying what type of computer program / language you use. But if you are into use R, this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/vignettes/sdm.pdf) on species distribution modeling might be useful.

It has examples about reading in data files, extracting values from rasters, fitting a model, and predicting.

Comment: Thank you @RobertH . Actually the mentioned case (Vignette) deals with points feature. My question about when we deal with such feature but in raster format. Any suggestions? thank you again.